# Late 80's/early 90's paperback about a young girl with pyrokinesis, not "Firestarter"

Tags: story-identification, books, telekinesis

In the late 80's/early 90's, I read a drugstore paperback that featured a teenage girl with pyrokinesis. She may have also had telekinesis. Sometime towards the beginning of the book, she kills some baby ducklings or birds?

Later in the book, it gets pretty racy. I remember there being a big fire at the end. I feel like I'd recognize the book if I see it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you recall the cover art?  Did it take place in the modern world?  Was there a recognizable locale visited?